# Smooth animations with AngularJS and ngAnimate?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, animation

The issue I'm having is when I use the animation hooks provided by `ngAnimate` the animation and how it affects other elements around it is very choppy.  Compared to something like the show/hide feature of jQuery which creates very smooth transitions.

Here is a **[sample plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rgF4iOGVDV4ukgHTcl6i?p=preview)**.

CSS:

```
.animate-show-hide.ng-hide {
 opacity: 0;
}

.animate-show-hide.ng-hide-add,
.animate-show-hide.ng-hide-remove {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
```

As you can see when you hide using ngAnimate the element fades off and the element below just abruptly snaps up.  With jQuery the element below smoothly transitions up while the element is fading away.

How can I achieve this type of smooth transition effect with `ngAnimate`?

UPDATE:
To clarify, I'm looking for a generalized solution, not specifically one that will only work with the example given.  The elements I will be applying this animation to vary in size or styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just animate all needed css attributes and you will be fine like in this **[demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HwrBUeQOatPLeZOYVQrN?p=preview)**.

```
.content-area {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width:95%;
}

.animate-show-hide {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  height:25px; 
  width:95%;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.animate-show-hide.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top:0;
  height:0;
  width:0%;
  padding:0;
}
```

---

#### A general solution for animations:

You always need to manipulate the css-attributes you want to animate. `jQuery` animations are special. `jQuery` look up for all css-bindings on an  element and manipulates those who are needed for an animation (for example `show` /  `hide` will check for all border-box css bindings (*padding, margin, height, width. etc.*) & *opacity*). `ngAnimate` is still very simple because it fully depends on raw css-animations. You could write an directive to make it work like in `jQuery` but IMO you will be fine by achieve that via plane css.

The main advantage of using css based animation is performance. All css animations are hardware accelerated. You should focus a solution based on css animation instead of manipulating css-attribute values via JavaScript.

A nice helper is [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). By taking a look at this lib you will see, there is no "general solution" for animations, because all animation depending on what they made for. For example: An "wobble" animation does not animate a "hide".

Comment: Thanks this does work but it seems like it would be very specific to the element.  If I had multiple elements of varying sizes that I want to apply this animation effect too I would have to create a css-style for each individually.  Is there a more generalized way of achieving this goal where I can just apply a single style to anything i want animated and it will work?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know how *jQuery* is doing, put a very **high** animation time, like **30 seconds** (see picture attached) and inspect the element. You will see some properties change gradually :

```
overflow, width, height, padding, margin & opacity.
```

if you analyse how jQuery works, you'll realise it's changing the css values with **javascript**. So jQuery can **know the original size** of an element because it uses javascript.

Unfortunately, in **css you cannot** animate an element's height by writing height:auto;

But you can use some tricks, like animating the *max-width*, *max-height*, *padding*, *margin* and *font-size* (to avoid the last moment jump)

I tried this with your plunkr and got a pretty good result :

```
.sample-show-hide {
  transition: all linear 2s;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 1000px; /* something higher than your element */
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sample-show-hide.ng-hide {
  max-width: 0%;
  max-height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdKpz.png)